# How do I track random numbers with stateless services

Tags: database, random, architecture, microservices

I have a design problem that I'm looking for an efficient way to solve:

I have three instances of a single service running. Each instance is totally stateless and exposes a single endpoint `/token`. When the `/token` endpoint is called by a client, a random number is returned. The random number is generated by a non-repeating pseudo-random number generator which generates a unique random integer for the first n-times it is called and then repeat the same sequence the next n-times it is called. In other words, it's a repeating cycle of n values. So say `n = 20`, it'll return unique values within the range of 0 to 20 for the first 20 times it is called.

The problem here is: given that I have three instances of this service running, how do I avoid duplicating random integers since any of the services can't know what random value has been generated by either of them.

**Here's what I've done:**

- I have passed as enviroment variable, a seed value that ensures that all the services are generating the same random sequence.
- I have setup a database that each of these services can access remotely. It has a table with a single column `map` set to a default value of `0`
- When the client calls the `/token` endpoint of a service, the service increases the value in the `map` column by 1 and fetches the resulting value.
- I then return the random number this resulting value maps to in the random sequence

Is the above approach efficient ?
Could the services experience a race condition when trying to access the database row ?
Could this problem be solved without a database ?

Suggestions would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just eliminate the "stateless" (not really stateless) services and move the pseudo-random logic to the clients, which use the db directly to coordinate.  You don't actually need a db here, just a counter service with some consistency and availability guarantees.

Comment: You can use something like an LCG with a very large period that is "jumpable" or "leapable", just have the first service start at the beginning of the sequence, the second start 1/3 of the way through and the third start 2/3 of the way through.

Comment: REF: "I have passed as enviroment variable, a seed value that ensures that all the services are generating the same random sequence." 
How about setting different env values which ensures you get different values from separate deployments of your service?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like snowflake could be used -

Instead of regular integers, well they will be integers again but you will need to encode a bit of information inside them, you can construct them so they encode the information bitwise.

So let's say your integers will be 64 bits. You can leave x bits for service, you can leave y bits for seed and z bits for the "real" id.(for example datetime ticks).

Doing this you will have something like 0001 (serviceid) (x=4) 1010 (z=4) (your n=20) 0101....0 (56 bits for datetime ticks).

So now you can identify your generated numbers by serviceId, give them some seed (maybe configuration) and some "real" part.

More on snowflake you can probably find from [here](https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/a/2010/announcing-snowflake).